# SqlAlchemy Postgres JSON how to filter with question mark operator?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm struggling to convert this to an ORM filter query:

```
select count(*) from issues WHERE pending_notifications ? 'flooby';
```

pending_notifications is a JSONB field containing a simple JSON array.

I'm not sure how to structure the filter using the question mark operator

I believe a Postgres ARRAY would work like this:

```
query.filter(pending_notifications.any('flooby'))
```

But I'm using JSONB and the filter syntax is not the same.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`.op()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.op) method to use any verbatim operator:

```
query.filter(pending_notifications.op("?")("flooby"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that you're using [`JSONB`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB) as column data type, use the [`has_key()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB.Comparator.has_key) method:

```
query.filter(pending_notifications.has_key('flooby'))
```

which maps to the `?` operator. The method name is misleading in this context, but [PostgreSQL documentation for `jsonb` operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) describes `?` thusly:

> Does the string exist as a top-level key within the JSON value?

and so `has_key()` is somewhat aptly named.

An example:

```
In [21]: t = Table('t', metadata, Column('json', postgresql.JSONB))

In [28]: print(t.c.json.has_key('test'))
t.json ? :json_1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use raw sql in filter

```
from sqlalchemy import text

db.session.query(Issue).filter(text("pending_notifications ? 'flooby'")
```